# Visual Studio 2013 - Preventing "Find in File - Look in" from changing its location

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 - "Find in File - Look in:" option keeps changing its location depending on what window has focus. I find this behavior extremely annoying and I'm wondering if anyone have found a way to disable it.

thx

Comment: I do not have this with my install of VS2013 Express.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. Note that I'm using ultimate.